# Is possible to make a graph in Arc that can act like a Pivot graph.

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, graph

I have not really used Graphs in Arc that much.

I was wondering if it possible to make a graph that can be interactively changed to the selections that are input into it. Ideally something like a Pivot chart  - Where the selections are being made from the TOC.

**MadeUp Example**

There is a feature class of polylines that equals a total of 1000 kilometres 
I Need to make a sub selection of a total of 100  Kilometres

The selection is a based on a visual selection and cannot be Automated.

As I select different lines I like to have a fast way of summing the total sum of the lines together.

**My Workflow is**

For each polyline within my feature class I make a separate layer, I label each line with something short and I then make a map of all lines , that I use a reference for lines I like to turn on.

From the dataset I export the this table to Excel and create a pivot chart

I then select lines in Arc and then make these Selections.

This works Ok and does give me the Desired Results

**IDEAL OUTCOME**

Link my layers to a graph , that interactively updates as selections are made or not made on the TOC , taking a the Culmative of a common FLD ID to make the total

If not via a graph , Are there any other options I could look at

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're after - maybe a screenshot would help? There is a Pivot table function in Arc with Advanced. There are graphing tools though I'm not sure about automatically updating. If all you want to do is get the total length of the lines you have selected there's a simple way: open the attribute table, select some lines, right-click the length field, and choose Statistics. It will give you a number of statistics about the selected values, including sum which would be the total length.

Comment: Hi Chris , what I am looking for is kind of an interactive Pivot Chart , so as the lines are toggled on and off they appear on the graph that creates the sum of the lengths

Answer (score 1):

From my read of your question it sounds like you are after something like the [Dynamic Charting for ArcMap](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d403edf223a49e8b31bc6e69526b7b4) sample application:

> This sample allows the ArcMap user to display dynamic charts
>   summarizing lengths, area or any other numeric field of a layer. Only
>   layers with unique value renderers are supported. This download
>   includes source code.

I have not used the above nor pivot charts in Excel.